# how to set jquery cron values to model as its own format

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, jquery-ui, cron

I'm using jquery cron in my jade template and in node js I got such an object

[image]

how can I set as its own format `* * * * *` .

Comment: submit cron value instead of submitting individual fields using `$('#example1').cron("value");`